# ValueError: ['path'] while installing Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to install a new version of Numpy. I was getting an error for not having the Microsoft Visual C++, but I installed that so that's fine now. The only problem is that now I'm getting a new error:

```
    File "C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287,     
in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys()))
ValueError: ['path']
```

If necessary, I can provide the actual file in question. I'm not doing so right now because it's quite a large file (for my experience, at least).

I'm sorry if this is an obvious or silly question, I am just getting started with python. I was not able to find anything else on this website about this problem specifically, merely other people who have had different ValueError or pathing problems in unrelated circumstances.

Edit: I am working on Windows 10 and Anaconda, if that is relevant. I am sorry if those are not good choices, but I am only a student right now; I do not want to get something more complicated if I can avoid it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue when trying to install a different python package on my system.  After some debugging I found that the `query_vcvarsall` function in the `msvc9compiler.py` script makes sure that 4 required environment variables are present on your system ("include", "lib", "libpath" and "path").  Based on the error you're getting, the only one of these environment variables present on your system is "path".  So you need to either add environment variables that point to the write include, lib and libpath folders or fix your installation of your compiler so they get loaded automatically.